# QGIS - Atlas. Outputs missing

Tags: qgis, print-composer

This really teases me. Somehow the Atlas-function in Print Composer are missing some of my polygons from my layer, when doing a print. I´ve looked at them once again,- they are there, and the geometry is right, but not all them are printed. How to solve this?

Comment: Would need some more information. Can you see them in a normal print without the atlas feature? What version of QGIS? What OS? Post a screenshot of the print composer where the polygons can be seen and an output where they can't. Is it a PDF or Image your are generating?

Comment: So far I've discovered that polygons that contains holes won't be found by atlas. Furthermore it influences on the number of outputs if the naming of each file are linked to 2 fields from the table. It's 2.0 Dufour on Win 7. And by a normal print no conflicts comes up.

Comment: Is your data shareable? If you can create an issue on hub.qgis.org and attach a project which demonstrates this I'll take a look what's happening here.

Comment: Update. I´ve detected the problem. The process in Atlas with naming each output crashes at a certain point and therefore stops the process in producing the remaining outputs. In my test (tested it on 2 computers) the output-name is generated by 2 fields, - An areaname and unique-iD. Then I´ve tried by naming only with area-names, and it seems like, that those with the longest characters won´t be generated, where as if named with ID alone it all goes well. Can have something to do with the cache memory maybe. The map contains several layers placed above eachother and could be the reason?

Comment: As mentioned earlier ---> "polygons that contains holes won't be found by atlas" ---> this is not true as found out later on.

Comment: Update 2. Now it makes sense. The root of the problem is that my attributes were named with / and therefore the process naming the output crashes, because that aren´t allowed.

Comment: Can you file this as a bug on hub.qgis.org? The atlas feature should be sanitizing filenames so that this does not happen...

Comment: Yes I will do that.